# How to make MS Teams bot available only from certain@xyz.com domain (Without Authentication)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a working MS Teams bot. Now If I want to accept only requests only from a particular domain (@xyz.com).

So My Bot will be accessible to all users from xyz.com domain and for rest it should not be discovered. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to confirm if you bot is going into the main App Store. If it's not, you can "restrict" it by only uploading the manifest to the relevant 'company' store in that Tenant. However, if the app is going to be available more widely, or if your tenant has multiple user domains and you want to restrict within the *same* tenant even, then you should look to use middleware to do this. You can read more about [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and then have a look at the following samples: [teamsTenantFilteringMiddleware](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/3481a14c39d49719be0b6917fdc85afb5381602e/libraries/teams-scenarios/integrationBot/src/teamsTenantFilteringMiddleware.ts) (node) ([C# version](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/d6b6ca6dbbc101d624008d27402216a94b232f7d/tests/Teams/Roster/TeamsTenantFilteringMiddleware.cs)).

That middleware filters on tenant id, which might suit your use case, or if you need to check actual user email, you'll need to look that up per user. [This](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/d6b6ca6dbbc101d624008d27402216a94b232f7d/tests/Teams/Roster/TeamsTenantFilteringMiddleware.cs) link shows how to get a user's email (it's not supplied with each message to the bot, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by following:
The way I handled this is by programmatically using reading and slicing Email address of the user (e.g. John.Doe@email.com)

```
TeamsChannelAccount member = await TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.From.Id, cancellationToken);
string[] checkEmail = member.Email.ToLower().Split('@');
if (checkEmail[1].Equals("contoso.com") || checkEmail[1].Equals("email.com"))
{
//Business logic
}
```

Thanks.